# I/O file reading issue and packages

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my program run. I need to write a program to keep records and perform statistical analysis for a class of students. Data to be taken from text file. I'm using packages and i/o files first time and a bit stuck there. I got error: "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"!

Here are my classes:

```
public class ReadSource
{

        public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {

            Student lab4 [] = new Student[40];

            if (lab4.length > 40)
            {
                System.out.println("Too Many Records");
            }
            lab4 = Util.readFile("Data.txt", lab4);
            Statistics statlab4 = new Statistics();
            statlab4.findlow(lab4);

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("this is a test");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
}

public class Student
{
    private int SID;       //Student ID
    private Integer scores[] = new Integer[5];
    public int getSID() {
        return SID;
    }
    public void setSID(int SID) {
        this.SID = SID;
    }
    public Integer[] getScores() {
        return scores;
    }
    public void setScores(Integer[] scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    public String Print()
    {
        Student [] students = new Student[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
        {
            return ("SID: " + this.SID + "Scores" + this.scores);
        }
        return ("SID: " + this.SID + "Scores" + this.scores);
    }
}


public class Util
{
    public static Student [] readFile(String filename, Student [] stu)throws Exception
    {

        String x;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((x = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        fr.close();
        return stu;
    }
    Student a1[][] = new Student [40][6];  
    public static void read()
    {
    }
}
```

Please, help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: give complete file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to understand the error message thrown.

> I got error: "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Data.txt (The system cannot find the
>   file specified)"!

What do you understand from that? To me, it looks like the application (or the Java runtime) is saying that "I can't find the file named Data.txt". As a programmer, you should now ask yourself - does the file exist? If so; why can't the JRE (or my app) find it?

A possible explanation;

The file is stored here;

> c:\My Documents\stuff\Data.txt

And your application is here;

> c:\My Documents\programming\myapp.java

When the application searches for the file "Data.txt", it will look here;

> c:\My Documents\programming\Data.txt

Because this is `the relative path with respect to the application.` Change the paths, and you should solve your issue.